# R, ggplot2 qqplot using 2 vectors + straight line?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, statistics

I have 2 `data.frame` objects:

- df1
- df2

Both have one column = amount.

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(amount = c(119.00,191.41,69.00,396.80,245.00,24.50,300.00,149.77,599.01,397.65))
df2 <- data.frame(amount = c(60.00,336.38,115.37,220.01,60.00,611.88,189.78,129.98,34.90,45.00))
```

I want to make a qqplot using both of them and add a `y = x` straight line to see if they have same distribution.

I am using `qqplot(df1$amount, df2$amount) + abline()` but it doesn't work: `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`
Please advise.

Also please explain me if I have an almost straight line in qqplot but I have a "level" there - what does it mean?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You have an error from `ggplot2` but neither `qqplot` or `abline` are functions in that package (`qplot` and `geom_abline` are).

Comment: @Relasta thanks a lot, my mistake

Comment: @Relasta But how can I do the same with stat_qq which is part of ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `qqplot()` and `abline()` are base R functions from the packages 'stats' and 'graphics'. There is no need to use `+` from the 'ggplot2' package.

It is more convenient to gather the data in a single `data.frame`.

```
df <- data.frame(
"Amount_X" = c(119.00,191.41,69.00,396.80,245.00,24.50,300.00,149.77,599.01,397.65), 
"Amount_Y" = c(60.00,336.38,115.37,220.01,60.00,611.88,189.78,129.98,34.90,45.00)
)
```

A base R solution for the plot then would be as follows:

```
qqplot(df$Amount_X, df$Amount_Y)
abline(0,1)
```

[image]

Comment: But how can I do the same with stat_qq which is part of ggplot2 @m-a